# jQuery : how to interrupt the hover on unhover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how to go about interrupting the hover function with an unhover function?

For eg , 
I have a circle(made by css : border-radius=half of width ,where width=height) on webpage , on hovering it , it starts to increase its width and height from 200px to 500px , also the border radius from 100px to 250px.. and the reverse on unhover.

But as i notice , the animation is completed till the end even when i unhover it

The eg as demonstrated above has the following code:

```
<script>
    $("#circle").hover(function() {
                $(this).animate({height:"500px" , width:"500px" ,  borderRadius:"250px"},1500);
                       },
        function unAnimate() {
                $(this).animate({height:"200px" , width:"200px" ,  borderRadius:"100px"},750);
        }
 );


</script>
```

Comment: use `$(this).stop().animate(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `border-radius` to `50%` it will always be a  circle.
I created a snippet for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#circle').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({width: 300, height: 300}, 1500);
  }, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({width: 100, height: 100}, 750);
  });
});
```

```css
#circle{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

}

.nice-gradient{
  background: rgb(254,204,177);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%, rgba(241,116,50,1) 50%, rgba(234,85,7,1) 51%, rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,204,177,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(241,116,50,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(234,85,7,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(251,149,94,1)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%,rgba(241,116,50,1) 50%,rgba(234,85,7,1) 51%,rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%,rgba(241,116,50,1) 50%,rgba(234,85,7,1) 51%,rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%,rgba(241,116,50,1) 50%,rgba(234,85,7,1) 51%,rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(254,204,177,1) 0%,rgba(241,116,50,1) 50%,rgba(234,85,7,1) 51%,rgba(251,149,94,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feccb1', endColorstr='#fb955e',GradientType=1 );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle" class="nice-gradient"></div>
```